# C: Suppress system calls from binary

Tags: c, string, gcc, binary

I have in my code things like:

```
system("a system call");
```

but, as the `printf`, the text inside the `system()` is readable in the binary code.

I'm compiling the `.c` with

```
gcc -std=gnu99 code.c -o code
```

How may I compile to suppress the readable string in the binary code?

Comment: On which operating system? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: There isn't a standard way to do it.  You can use any manual technique you like, presumably encrypting or masking the text of the string before compiling and and decrypting or unmasking the text at runtime before making the call to the function.  But it is generally speaking more work than it is worth (and the security provided by it is rather minimal),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know on which operating system you are coding. But I am guessing it is Linux (or at least some POSIX).

Then my advice is to **avoid [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)** and use something else, such as [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html); take time to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for details (they could be tricky to you).

BTW, you are naive in thinking that by removing the string from your binary, people won't be able to understand what is happening. They could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and guess immediately what programs and arguments your program is running (even if you encrypt the command string, etc...)

BTW, security thru obscurity is wrong.

At last, a bit of terminology: [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is a [standard C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) function (very poorly named, it should have been called `command`), it is not a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), which are listed (on Linux) in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could "encrypt" the string and store the crypted version. Then when the program needs the ASCII string, decrypt it.

The most simple encrypter is to do a bitwise xor with a random pattern of bits. To decrypt simply do the same bitwise xor with exacly the same random pattern of bits.

You will need to save the string length along with the encrypted byte sequence.

Here are simple encryption and decryption functions. These are not cryptographically secure, but good enough for the goal.
You can use a global constant as key.

```
void encrypt(char* str, unsigned long key)
{
  unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)str, c;
  do
  {
    key = key * 214013L + 2531011L;
    c = *p;
    *p ^= (unsigned char)(key>>24);
    ++p;
  }
  while(c);
}

void decrypt(char* str, unsigned long key)
{
  unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)str;
  do
  {
    key = key * 214013L + 2531011L;
    *p ^= (unsigned char)(key>>24);
  }
  while(*p++);
}
```

Comment: `s/encryption/encraption`. There's a gnu C function for that: `memfrob()`.

Comment: @EOF, thanks for the hint. I would however avoid using `memfrob()` because each byte is xored with the constant 42. It's too easy to undo in a brute force way.

Comment: OMG, you're right! All my encryption schemes are plummeting down, if only I'd have selected a different single-byte key for my mono-alphabetic encryption every time. Oh well, too late now.